# VHDL Finite State Machine not transitioning correctly based on external signal

Tags: vhdl, simulation, fsm

I'm currently working on a VHDL project involving a finite state machine (FSM) that transitions through three states (STATE_0, STATE_1, and STATE_2) based on an external signal T. Each state should wait for a certain number of pulses from T before transitioning to the next state.

The behavior I'm expecting is as follows:

When in STATE_0, the FSM should transition to STATE_1 after receiving 2 pulses from T.
When in STATE_1, it should transition to STATE_2 after receiving 4 pulses.
When in STATE_2, it should transition back to STATE_0 after receiving 6 pulses.
However, my FSM implementation doesn't seem to be behaving correctly. It's not transitioning states as expected, and I suspect there might be issues with how I'm handling the counter and state transitions.

I've provided the VHDL code below, along with a waveform file from my simulation (used Quartus II 9.0 web edition). The code compiles correctly.

Take into account I am a complete beginner in VHDL and this is my first question in Stack Overflow, so any feedback on how to better the way I ask questions will be highly appreciated.

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity STLC is
Port (
clk, T : in STD_LOGIC;
state_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0)
);
end entity STLC;

architecture Behavioral of STLC is
type state_type is (STATE_0, STATE_1, STATE_2);
signal current_state, next_state : state_type;
signal counter : integer range 0 to 63 := 0; -- Inner counter to track state durations
signal B : integer range 0 to 63 := 0;

begin

    state_transition_process: process(current_state, counter)
    begin
        case current_state is
                when STATE_0 =>
                    if counter - B > 2 then
                        next_state <= STATE_1;
                        B <= counter;  -- Reset counter
                    else 
                        next_state <= STATE_0;
                    end if;
                when STATE_1 =>
                    if counter - B > 4 then
                        next_state <= STATE_2;
                        B <= counter;  -- Reset counter
                    else 
                        next_state <= STATE_1;
                    end if;
                when STATE_2 =>
                    if counter - B > 6 then
                        next_state <= STATE_0;
                        B <= counter;  -- Reset counter
                    else 
                        next_state <= STATE_2;
                    end if;                    
                when others =>
                    next_state <= STATE_0;
            end case;
    end process;
    
    -- Output logic
    output_logic: process (current_state)
    begin
        case current_state is
            when STATE_0 =>
                state_out <= "00";
            when STATE_1 =>
                state_out <= "01";
            when STATE_2 =>
                state_out <= "10";
            when others =>
                state_out <= "00";  -- Default state
        end case;
    end process output_logic;
    
    -- State flip-flop
    state_ff: process (clk)
    begin
        if clk'event and clk='1' then
            current_state <= next_state;
            if T='1' then
                counter <= counter + 1;  -- Increment counter on T signal activation
            end if;
        end if;
    end process state_ff;

end architecture Behavioral;
```

[Updated simulation after adding B to sensitivity list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCTN8.png)

Could someone please review my code and provide guidance on what might be causing this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I've implemented a finite state machine in VHDL, specifying the transitions between states based on the number of pulses received from the external signal T. I've coded the logic for each state transition and initialized counters to track the number of pulses. However, despite my efforts, the FSM isn't transitioning states as expected. I expected the FSM to transition from STATE_0 to STATE_1 after 2 pulses, from STATE_1 to STATE_2 after 4 pulses, and from STATE_2 back to STATE_0 after 6 pulses.

Comment: In the waveform state_out Changes to x at the falling Edge of T. This Change cannot be caused by your Design, because Changes at T are only checked at rising clock edges. So the cause of the X values must be your Testbench. Please add the Testbench Code to your question.

Comment: You never reset counter, so when counter ist incremented to 64, you will get a simulation Error, because counter ist Limited to 63.

Comment: I must admit that I haven't used any testbench on my VHDL design because I currently lack the knowledge to create one. Instead, I tested it by simulating the behavior, specifying only the values of T and clk in the waveform file.
Upon reflection, I realize that I inadvertently performed a timing simulation rather than a functional one, which explains the observed delay in the response. Now that I've rectified this and switched the simulation to functional, the delay is no longer present. However, the strange behavior of undefined values persists, and I'm still troubleshooting it.

Comment: I've updated the screenshot to reflect the switch to functional simulation, nonetheless the issue with undefined values still persists.

Comment: The `state_transition_process` is missing `B` from the sensitivity list, meaning the state transitions are not likely correct. As to why you have XXs on the waveform I dont know, as XX should not be possible. I would highly recommend not using the Quartus 9 simulator. Not only is it 15 years old, it only performs simulations on compiled netlists, not RTL simulations. GHDL is a free and open source VHDL simulator that is regularly updated. I also recommend writing a testbench.

Comment: I've made modifications to the code by adding `B` to the sensitivity list of the `state_transition_process`, recompiled it, and rerun the simulation. Unfortunately, the issue persists. Also, I added `counter` and `B` signals to the simulation to monitor their behavior. Surprisingly, `B` remains at its initial value of 0 throughout the simulation, indicating that it's not being updated as expected within the process. (See new simulation results).

Regarding to my usage of Quartus 9, it is the software our college make as use…

Comment: You dont show current state or next state on the waveform. Please add them

Comment: I'm unable to locate the `current_state` and `next_state` signals in the node finder, which should be straightforward. However, they literally don't appear. Unfortunately, the support I've received from my professors regarding this older software is quite limited and I do not know how else I can provide context or troubleshoot this problem further.

Comment: So this problem likely stems from the fact that you are not simulating the RTL, but a netlist. I suspect a lack of reset might be causing a problem. You probably cannot find the state signals as they have been optimised away leaving only the state_out bits. I recommend getting help from the professors. There is otherwise nothing wrong with the code, other than lack of testbench.

Comment: I tested your design with a testbench. It works without generating X's. But the state switches take place after 3,6,7 pulses instead of 2,4,6. And as expected, there is a simulation error when counter reaches 64. Adding B to the sensitivity list has no influence. When designing FSMs, consider using a tool like [HDL-FSM-Editor](http://www.hdl-fsm-editor.de).

Comment: Hi, thank you both so much for your time! I've reached out to my professor regarding this issue and am currently awaiting a response. Once I receive it, I'll promptly post the solution here and mark the question as closed.